# Anonymous functions in java

Tags: java, anonymous-function

I have a class called LinkGroup which holds some game objects. I call Rotate to set some rotation variables for these objects. Whenever my game hits its update loop, I rotate the objects according to the rotation variables. If they've rotated enough, I fire an onComplete callback.

The following code works...

```
public void Rotate(){
    _currentRotation = _0;
    _targetRotation = 180; //degrees
    _rotationSpeed = 50;

    try{
        _onComplete = LinkGroup.class.getDeclaredMethod("rotateComplete", null);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){

    }
}
```

...but this is ugly.

I don't like having to declare the method rotateComplete and manually link it to Rotate via a string. Is there something similar to anonymous functions in C# so I can just declared the rotateComplete method inside the Rotate method?

For bonus points, is there a better way to implement the required exception handling for "getDeclaredMethod"? Terseness is a preference.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "Anonymous Function" (or "Method Group") in Java. *However*, the ["Anonymous Class"](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~tmh/courses/allJava/Anonymous.html) construct might a be worth exploring ..

Comment: Is `rotateComplete()` a method of `LinkGroup` class?

Comment: @ShivamKalra: yes, rotateComplete is a method of LinkGroup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my understanding, I believe you are trying to call `onRotateComplete()` method in the `LinkGroup` class whenever some game object is been rotated. You can use the pattern that Java Swing uses for handling button clicks or other events: This could be done this way:

Define an interface

```
interface IRotateHandler {
    public void onRotateComplete();
}
```

Change the `Rotate()` to `Rotate(IRotateHandler handler)` and then in `LinkGroup` class you can call your game object like this.

```
gameObject.Rotate(new IRotateHandler() {
    public void onRotateComplete() {
        /* do your stuff!
    }
}
```

Comment: This method ended up cleaning up my code via interface usage as well, so it gets the win. I've upvoted the answer of @Mankarse too.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `getDeclaredMethod`. Just make `_onComplete` be a `Runnable` (or something similar), and create an anonymous class:

```
public void Rotate(){
    _currentRotation = _0;
    _targetRotation = 180; //degrees
    _rotationSpeed = 50;

    _onComplete = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                rotateComplete();
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 doesn't yet have closures.  [Java 8 will.](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/)  So, for the time being, there's no way to write that function anonymously in Java.

As for the error handling, a quick [glance at the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) shows me that you throw two `RuntimeExceptions` and a `ReflectiveOperationException`.  Catching `Exception` may be your best bet, unless you wanted to catch all three of these possible exceptions differently, and take different action based on each.